# Geometry polygon to lat long on postgis

Tags: php, postgresql, google-maps-api-3, yii2, postgis

I need to convert potsgres geometry data type to lat long.

This is my table
[image]

geom column stores coordinates but they are not human readable.

I just cant figure out how I can get every single point that makes a polygon.

There are some output options for geometry data type `https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs`.

I need every point lat long because I have to use them in this code to define and render a polygon on google maps

```
$coords = [
          new LatLng(['lat' => 25.774252, 'lng' => -80.190262]),
          new LatLng(['lat' => 18.466465, 'lng' => -66.118292]),
          new LatLng(['lat' => 32.321384, 'lng' => -64.75737]),
        ];

        $polygon = new Polygon([
          'paths' => $coords
        ]);
```

The problem is that I cant access lat long to define points that meakes up a polygon.

I'm using YII2, yii2-google-maps extension, PostGis Postgress.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For displaying geometries in [`WKT`](http://giswiki.org/wiki/Well_Known_Text) use the function [`ST_AsText`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsText.html):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom) FROM colonias
```

In case you prefer [`GeoJSON`](http://geojson.org/) or [`GML`](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/gml), use the following functions:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) FROM colonias;
SELECT ST_AsGML(geom) FROM colonias
```

See also this [`other answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49905336/2275388) for more output formats in PostGIS.

To split longitude and latitude use the functions [`ST_X`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [`ST_Y`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html):

```
SELECT ST_X(geom),ST_Y(geom) FROM colonias
```

In case your geometries are not points, you have to first extract the points using [`ST_DumpPoints`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html) an then parse them as described above. A straightforward way to do so is using [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/queries-with.html) (aka WITH clause).

Example:

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT 
  (ST_DumpPoints(
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((2 0,2 3,0 2,2 0))'))).geom AS point
) 
SELECT ST_X(j.point), ST_Y(j.point) FROM j;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9805eeefc0264eb3f468015d6ce23495)

Comment: I could solve this using ST_DumpPoints to split polygons into points, then ST_X ST_Y to get lat/long as separate variables.

Comment: If your geometries are already points, there is no need for using `st_dumppoints`. But in case you have polygons, there is indeed no other way. I'll add it to my answer

Comment: They are no points, they are polygons, If I only use ST_AsText "geom" column will transform to lat lon. So every cell on "geom" colum will store a bunch of points but they are not individually selectable. The way I did allows me to do  "new LatLng(['lat' => datum["st_y"], 'lng' => [st_x])", It allows me to access data as array.