# convert Postgres geometry format to WKT

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a Postgres table which stores polygon geometry in its specific format in one of the column, something like this-

```
0103000020E61000000100000004000000B8627F336B1554405DD602FFA2733A40B8627FA7601554403851F8EBC7723A40B8627FC38F15544036D539E90B733A40B8627F336B1554405DD602FFA2733A40
```

I know how to convert this single value to WKT using `ST_AsText` which will give me POLYGON((Lat Long)). But I want to convert whole column into WKT format.

How to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT ST_AsText(your_geom_column) FROM your_table;
```

In the following examples I'll show you a few other ways to serialise your geometries. Consider this data sample with two points encoded as 4326 (WGS84):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp 
  (geom GEOMETRY);
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES 
  ('SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)'),
  ('SRID=4326;POINT(2 4)');
```

Geometries as [`WKB`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsBinary.html) (Well-Known Binary, default):

```
SELECT geom FROM tmp;

 geom                        
----------------------------------------------------
 0101000020E6100000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
 0101000020E610000000000000000000400000000000001040
```

Geometries as [`WKT`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) (Well-Known Text) and [`EWKT`](https://dbfiddle.uk/3wJa1KOE) (Just like WKT but with an explicit Spatial Reference System):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom), ST_AsEWKT(geom) FROM tmp;

 st_astext  | st_asewkt       
------------+----------------------
 POINT(1 2) | SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)
 POINT(2 4) | SRID=4326;POINT(2 4)
```

In case you fancy [`GeoJSON`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html)

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) FROM tmp;

 st_asgeojson             
--------------------------------------
 {"type":"Point","coordinates":[1,2]}
 {"type":"Point","coordinates":[2,4]}
```

Or even [`GML`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGML.html)

```
SELECT ST_AsGML(geom) FROM tmp;

 st_asgml                                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:coordinates>1,2</gml:coordinates></gml:Point>
 <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:coordinates>2,4</gml:coordinates></gml:Point>
```

The Google Earth enthusiasts also have their fun! Geometries as `KML`

```
SELECT ST_AsKML(geom) FROM tmp;

 st_askml                    
-----------------------------------------------
 <Point><coordinates>1,2</coordinates></Point>
 <Point><coordinates>2,4</coordinates></Point>
```

Librarians might also wanna take a look at [`ST_AsMARC21`](https://postgis.net/docs//ST_AsMARC21.html) (added in 3.3)

```
SELECT ST_AsMARC21(geom) FROM tmp;
                                                                                                                                            st_asmarc21
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"><datafield tag="034" ind1="1" ind2=" "><subfield code="a">a</subfield><subfield code="d">E0010000</subfield><subfield code="e">E0010000</subfield><subfield code="f">N0020000</subfield><subfield code="g">N0020000</subfield></dataf
ield></record>
 <record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"><datafield tag="034" ind1="1" ind2=" "><subfield code="a">a</subfield><subfield code="d">E0020000</subfield><subfield code="e">E0020000</subfield><subfield code="f">N0040000</subfield><subfield code="g">N0040000</subfield></dataf
ield></record>
(2 rows)
```

And the list goes on! In the PostGIS documentation there are [other fancy ways to serialise geometries](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Outputs).

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/3wJa1KOE)