# Postgis geometry format manipulation

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Hello I have 2 questions about postgis geometry format:

How can I determine what is this geometry format (ewkb, hexewkb ...)?

`"0101000020110F0000000000003087094100000080B6415741"`

How to convert wkt to EWKB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a geometry is valid (regardless of format) you can use [`ST_IsValid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html) - or [`ST_IsValidReason`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidReason.html) in case you wanna know why it fails.

```
SELECT ST_IsValid('0101000020110F0000000000003087094100000080B6415741');
 st_isvalid 
------------
 t
(1 Zeile)
```

If for whatever reason you want to test if the geometry is encoded in a certain format, try the `ST_GeomFrom*` functions and catch the error message in case it fails, e.g.

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromWKB('POINT(1 2)');
FEHLER:  Invalid endian flag value encountered.


SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(1 2)');
              st_geomfromtext               
--------------------------------------------
 0101000000000000000000F03F0000000000000040
(1 Zeile)
```

To convert it to `EWKB` try [`ST_AsEWKB`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEWKB.html)

```
SELECT ST_AsEWKB('0101000020110F0000000000003087094100000080B6415741');
                      st_asewkb                       
------------------------------------------------------
 \x0101000020110f0000000000003087094100000080b6415741
(1 Zeile)
```

Further reading: [`Convert geometry to various formats`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905207/convert-postgres-geometry-format-to-wkt/49905336#49905336)