# How to refer to 2 column names in python?

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, geopandas

I'm trying to retrieve a database with geometry information from a SQL server in Python using `sqlalchemy` and `geopandas`. There are 2 columns in geometry format and I want to retain both. The code I'm using is

```
import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_connection_url = "postgresql://username:password@host:5432/database"
con = create_engine(db_connection_url)  
sql = 'SELECT osm_id, way, tags, way_centroid FROM osm.bldg WHERE height IS NOT NULL;'
df = gpd.read_postgis(sql, con, geom_col='way')
```

I want to achieve something similar in R which is `geom_col = c('way', 'way_centroid')` for the function`gpd.real_postgis`, but I'm aware that it's not going to work this way in python. How can I achieve this in python?

Comment: There is a wrong comma right before the `FROM`. It should be `SELECT osm_id, way, tags, way_centroid FROM osm.bldg ...`

Comment: @JimJones Thanks for pointing it out. I totally didn't notice that when I was trying to delete some script from the SELECT clause...

Comment: I don't *think* geopandas supports two primary geometry columns, though I think there's no reason why you couldn't have a another column of type GeometryArray. That said, since your second set of geometries is a centroid, could you use BigQuery's geospatial directives, e.g. [`st_x`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_x) and [`st_y`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_y) to extract the x and y values as additional float columns?

Answer (score 2):

I somehow managed to modify the sql query to change the geometry to WKT before I fetch the data in python using `psycopg2` instead...

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd

connection = psycopg2.connect(user="username",
                                  password="password",
                                  host="host",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="database")
cursor = connection.cursor()
postgreSQL_select_Query = 'SELECT osm_id, ST_ASTEXT(way), tags, ST_ASTEXT(way_centroid) FROM osm.bldg WHERE height IS NOT NULL;'

cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
print("Selected rows from database")
records = cursor.fetchall()

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df.columns=['osm_id', 'way', 'tags', 'way_centroid']
df
```

Comment: Related post: in this answer I show a few other ways to serialize geometries (perhaps geojson is also interesting for you): https://stackoverflow.com/a/49905336/2275388

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct way to store two geometries, but you can directly convert centroid coordinates to floats using the [`st_x`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_x) and [`st_y`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_x) geography functions:

```py
db_connection_url = "postgresql://username:password@host:5432/database"
con = create_engine(db_connection_url)  

sql = '''
SELECT (
    osm_id,
    tags,
    st_x(way_centroid) as centroid_x,
    st_y(way_centroid) as centroid_y,
    way
)
FROM osm.bldg
WHERE height IS NOT NULL;
'''

df = gpd.read_postgis(sql, con, geom_col='way')
```