# Data mismatch in AWS DMS Bulk load vs CDC

Tags: postgresql, postgis, aws-dms

I have a postgis database(source) for which i have done DMS and moved it to S3 bucket(target) in parquet file.
There is a column name point of datatype-geometry(point, 4326) in the source which converts to string after dms and looks like this in target-

-In bulk load it is like -`point": "<Point srsName=\"EPSG:4326\"><coordinates>72.836903300000003,19.0823766</coordinates></Point>"`

-In CDC it is like -`point": "0101000020E610000051D77F4262855EC09591C4DCFFB54240"`

I am able to get the coordinates back from the string in full load by string parsing but during CDC it is in some random hexadecimal string from which I am not aware how to decode back to the coordinates.

Comment: Use ST_AsText(point) for clear text coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

In PostgreSQL in order to display geometries in a format other than WKB you have to explicitly state it in your query. In your case [`ST_AsGML`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGML.html):

```
SELECT ST_AsGML('0101000020E610000051D77F4262855EC09591C4DCFFB54240');

                                               st_asgml                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><gml:coordinates>-122.0841223,37.4218708</gml:coordinates></gml:Point>
(1 row)
```

Or something like this if you wish to omit the namespace (as your example suggests):

```
SELECT ST_AsGML('0101000020E610000051D77F4262855EC09591C4DCFFB54240', 15, 0, '', '');

                                       st_asgml                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><coordinates>-122.0841223,37.4218708</coordinates></Point>
(1 row)
```

See also: [`Converting geometries in PostGIS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49905336/2275388)