# Different GEO representations

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

Why does one of the following notations print a readable string, `(100,200)` whereas the others show a binary format?

```
SELECT geography 'POINT(100 200)', 
       point '100,200', 
       geography(point) 'POINT(100 200)'
```

[image]

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1cd06e002ab74b70189f908cafb7e17b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`geometry` and `geography` are geographic data types from the extension [`PostGIS`](https://postgis.net/) and `point` is a PostgreSQL [`geometric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-geometric.html#id-1.5.7.16.5) data type. If you're planing to store latitude and longitude values I suggest you to use PostGIS, as it provides plenty of handy functions out of the box and it is very easy to use.

The binary value you're seeing is a WKB ([`Well Known Binary`](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#OpenGISWKBWKT)) representation of the geometry - standard representation. There are [`many other ways`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49905336/2275388) to serialize geometries.